# How to highlight active page link in JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, css, jsp, servlets

I have header.jsp, footer.jsp. I am including these accordingly in jsp page and getting required layouts. In header I have 3 menu links. I need to highlight the list menu accordingly based on current page. Using jQuery I am doing, it highlights for a moment and when new page comes it disappears. I think while clicking it reloads fresh JavaScript file. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

JSP is a server side technology and jquery is a client side technology.

Setting any "state" of your application by using jquery will be lost as soon as you refresh your page by following a link or just pressing F5 (page refresh).

The state of a jsp is maintained by the server and it can have multiple scopes. You should maintain the "active link" within the server by checking the current rendered jsp. You can do this in your "header". You have to associate the current url (e.g. request url) with an menu item.

Set a simple css tag or class that will indicate an active menu.

Have a look at this:

http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/highlight-current-page.php

Comment: Thanks! It gives a hint. Let me try then coming back.

Comment: Ya thanks again! it works. I added jquery in my header.jsp and if-else cond. But is this the only way?